# How to use Relation in more then three table in a single entity using Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

Here i am new in Room Database,my question is i want to get data form more then three tables. In the main table i am having codes and their code relate to other table with their name. I want to select name on the behalf of code.
As seen in this link.I need the desired output using @Relation.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t6Wk.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple **working example** based upon your image. It consists of 4 Entities (tables). A fifth POJO `ChildDetails` object that has the relationship by embedding the Child and relating the other 3 tables.

A single Dao has been used. This includes inserts and queries.

Note that for ease and brevity it runs on the main thread.

First the Entities :-

**School**

```
@Entity(tableName = "school_table")
public class School {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "schoolcode")
    Long schoolCode;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "schoolname")
    String schoolName;

    School() {
    }

    @Ignore
    School(String schoolName) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
}
```

**Block**

```
@Entity(tableName = "block_table")
public class Block {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "blockcode")
    Long blockCode;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "blockname")
    String blockName;
}
```

**Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "class_table")
public class Class {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "classcode")
    Long classCode;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "classname")
    String className;
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity(tableName = "child_table")
public class Child {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="childcode")
    Long childCode;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "childname")
    String childName;

    @NonNull
    Long classCode;

    @NonNull
    Long schoolCode;

    @NonNull
    Long blockCode;
}
```

The **ChildDetails** POJO with the **@Realtion**'s

```
class ChildDetails {

    @Embedded()
    Child child;
    @Relation(entity = School.class,parentColumn = "schoolCode",entityColumn = "schoolcode")
    School school;
    @Relation(entity = Block.class,parentColumn = "blockCode",entityColumn = "blockcode")
    Block block;
    @Relation(entity = Class.class,parentColumn = "classCode",entityColumn = "classcode")
    Class clss;
}
```

The Dao for all **AllDao**

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    /* Simple Inserts */
    @Insert
    Long insertSchool(School school);

    @Insert
    Long insertBlock(Block block);

    @Insert
    Long insertClass(Class c);

    @Insert
    Long insertChild(Child child);

    /* Get individual Objects */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM school_table WHERE schoolcode = :schoolcode")
    School getSchoolBySchoolCode(Long schoolcode);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM block_table WHERE blockcode = :blockcode")
    Block getBlockByBlockCode(Long blockcode);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM class_table WHERE classcode = :classcode")
    Class getClassByClassCode(Long classcode);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM  child_table WHERE childcode = :childcode")
    Child getChildByChildCode(Long childcode);

    /* Get row counts */
    @Query("SELECT count() FROM school_table")
    Long getSchoolCount();

    @Query("SELECT count() FROM block_table")
    Long getBlockCount();

    @Query("SELECT count() FROM class_table")
    Long getClassCount();

    @Query("SELECT count() FROM child_table")
    Long getChildCount();

    /* Long winded */
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM child_table " +
            "JOIN school_table ON child_table.schoolCode =  school_table.schoolcode " +
            "JOIN block_table ON child_table.blockCode = block_table.blockcode " +
            "JOIN class_table ON child_table.classCode = class_table.classcode WHERE childname = :childname")
    ChildDetails getChildDetails(String childname);

    /* Easier version */
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM child_table WHERE childname = :childname")
    ChildDetails othergetChildDetails(String childname);
}
```

The @Database **Database**

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {School.class,Block.class,Class.class,Child.class},version = 1)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {

    static final String DBNAME = "schooling";
    abstract AllDao allDao();

}
```

Finally an Activity **MainActivity** that adds and retrieves data culminating in getting the related data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database db;
    AllDao allDao;
    String TAG = "SCHOOLING";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,Database.class,Database.DBNAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        allDao = db.allDao();


        allDao.insertSchool(new School("School1"));
        allDao.insertSchool(new School("School2"));
        School s = new School();
        s.schoolName = "School3";
        allDao.insertSchool(s);
        Log.d(TAG,"School Count = " + Long.toString(allDao.getSchoolCount()));

        Block b = new Block();
        b.blockName = "Block1";
        allDao.insertBlock(b);
        b.blockName = "Block2";
        allDao.insertBlock(b);
        b.blockName = "Block3";
        allDao.insertBlock(b);
        Log.d(TAG,"Block Count = " + allDao.getBlockCount());

        Class c = new Class();
        c.className = "Class1";
        allDao.insertClass(c);
        c.className = "Class2";
        allDao.insertClass(c);
        c.className = "Class3";
        allDao.insertClass(c);
        Log.d(TAG,"Class Count =" + allDao.getClassCount());

        Child chld = new Child();
        chld.childName = "Tom";
        chld.schoolCode = 2L;
        chld.blockCode = 1L;
        chld.classCode = 3L;
        allDao.insertChild(chld);

        chld.childName = "Sue";
        chld.classCode = 2L;
        allDao.insertChild(chld);

        chld.childName = "Ann";
        chld.schoolCode = 3L;
        chld.blockCode = 3L;
        chld.classCode = 1L;
        allDao.insertChild(chld);
        Log.d(TAG,"Child Count = " + allDao.getChildCount());

        // Data has been added so extract data as ChildDetails objects
        // Using SELECT with JOINS encoded (long winded)
        logChildDetails("Sue");
        logChildDetails("Tom");
        logChildDetails("Ann");

        // Using defined relationships (concise)
        otherlogChildDetails("Sue");
        otherlogChildDetails("Tom");
        otherlogChildDetails("Ann");

    }

    private void logChildDetails(String childname) {
        ChildDetails cd = allDao.getChildDetails(childname);
        Log.d(TAG,"Child Details for Child " + childname + " Are:- " +
                "\nChild Name=" + cd.child.childName + " ChildCode = " + cd.child.childCode +
                "\nSchool Name =" + cd.school.schoolName + " SchoolCode = " + cd.school.schoolCode +
                "\nBlock Name =" + cd.block.blockName + " BlockCode =  " +cd.block.blockCode +
                "\nClass Name =" + cd.clss.className + " ClassCode = " + cd.clss.classCode
        );
    }
    private void otherlogChildDetails(String childname) {
        ChildDetails cd = allDao.othergetChildDetails(childname);
        Log.d(TAG,"Child Details for Child " + childname + " Are:- " +
                "\nChild Name=" + cd.child.childName + " ChildCode = " + cd.child.childCode +
                "\nSchool Name =" + cd.school.schoolName + " SchoolCode = " + cd.school.schoolCode +
                "\nBlock Name =" + cd.block.blockName + " BlockCode =  " +cd.block.blockCode +
                "\nClass Name =" + cd.clss.className + " ClassCode = " + cd.clss.classCode
        );
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** the above is not intended to be run multiple times (although it can be). It will replicate the data (although codes (aka id's) will be different).

**Results**

When run for the first time the following results will be seen in the LogCat :-

```
03-23 22:06:10.317 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: School Count = 3
03-23 22:06:10.330 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Block Count = 3
03-23 22:06:10.341 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Class Count =3
03-23 22:06:10.350 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Count = 3
03-23 22:06:10.352 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Sue Are:- 
    Child Name=Sue ChildCode = 2
    School Name =School2 SchoolCode = 2
    Block Name =Block1 BlockCode =  1
    Class Name =Class2 ClassCode = 2
03-23 22:06:10.354 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Tom Are:- 
    Child Name=Tom ChildCode = 1
    School Name =School2 SchoolCode = 2
    Block Name =Block1 BlockCode =  1
    Class Name =Class3 ClassCode = 3
03-23 22:06:10.356 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Ann Are:- 
    Child Name=Ann ChildCode = 3
    School Name =School3 SchoolCode = 3
    Block Name =Block3 BlockCode =  3
    Class Name =Class1 ClassCode = 1
03-23 22:06:10.358 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Sue Are:- 
    Child Name=Sue ChildCode = 2
    School Name =School2 SchoolCode = 2
    Block Name =Block1 BlockCode =  1
    Class Name =Class2 ClassCode = 2
03-23 22:06:10.359 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Tom Are:- 
    Child Name=Tom ChildCode = 1
    School Name =School2 SchoolCode = 2
    Block Name =Block1 BlockCode =  1
    Class Name =Class3 ClassCode = 3
03-23 22:06:10.360 5391-5391/a.a.so66757571javaroom4tables D/SCHOOLING: Child Details for Child Ann Are:- 
    Child Name=Ann ChildCode = 3
    School Name =School3 SchoolCode = 3
    Block Name =Block3 BlockCode =  3
    Class Name =Class1 ClassCode = 1
```

Comment: @Vani if you believe the answer helped you, please tick the answer to show this.